# Jmeter - Selenium/WebDriver : unable to resolve class org.openqa.selenium.support.ui

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

os
Ubuntu 20.04.6

java --version
openjdk 17.0.8.1 2023-08-24

Jmeter
v 5.6.2

Selenium/WebDriver Support
4.13.0.0

groovy script

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui as ui;

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('https://google.com')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

LOGS

```
2023-11-08 19:32:45,303 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2023-11-08 19:32:45,304 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2023-11-08 19:32:45,304 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2023-11-08 19:32:45,337 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2023-11-08 19:32:45,337 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2023-11-08 19:32:45,337 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2023-11-08 19:32:45,337 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2023-11-08 19:32:45,338 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2023-11-08 19:32:45,338 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2023-11-08 19:32:45,338 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2023-11-08 19:32:53,300 INFO c.g.j.p.w.c.WebDriverConfig: Created browser object: ChromeDriver: chrome on linux (null)
2023-11-08 19:32:53,326 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script3.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class org.openqa.selenium.support.ui
 @ line 14, column 1.
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui as ui;
   ^

1 error

2023-11-08 19:32:53,326 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2023-11-08 19:32:53,326 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2023-11-08 19:32:53,433 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2023-11-08 19:32:53,434 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

dir> jmeter/lib

-groovy-3.0.17.jar
-selenium-api-4.13.0.jar
-selenium-chrome-driver-4.13.0.jar
-selenium-chromium-driver-4.13.0.jar
-selenium-edge-driver-4.13.0.jar
-selenium-firefox-driver-4.13.0.jar
-selenium-http-4.13.0.jar
-selenium-ie-driver-4.13.0.jar
-selenium-json-4.13.0.jar
-selenium-os-4.13.0.jar
-selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar
-selenium-support-4.13.0.jar

i am new to Jmeter.
is there anything i missing ? is any path issues ?
i want to use WebDriverWait class but i am stuck at **unable to resolve class** issue
any groovy path issue ?
i think may be its because of any path mismatch but i dont know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `import` statement syntax is incorrect.

You can either go for [star import](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_star_import):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*
```

or [static star import](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_star_import):

```
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Program Structure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)